# Update Attribute for Unchecked Boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

I've got a form with checkboxes. The user (a classroom teacher) clicks the objectives he wants to be considered as pretests.

The controller then sets the :pretest value to "1" for each record that is checked.

The controller also needs to make sure that any unchecked boxes set the :pretest value to "0" for each record that is not checked.

So far, I'm doing this by first setting EVERYTHING to zero, and then updating the checked boxes. But I suspect that there is a more rails-y way of doing this.

Controller:

```
   def update_pretests
        @seminar = Seminar.find(params[:seminar_id])
        @seminar.objective_seminars.update_all(:pretest => 0)
        ObjectiveSeminar.where(:id => params[:pretest_on]).update_all(:pretest => 1)
    end
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag update_pretests_objective_seminars_path do %>
    <input type="hidden" name="seminar_id" value="<%= @seminar.id %>">

    <table>
        <% @os.each do |os| %>
            <% obj = os.objective %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= check_box_tag 'pretest_on[]', os.id, os.pretest > 0, {:id => "pretest_on_#{obj.id}"} %></td>
                <td><%= obj.name %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>

    <%= submit_tag "Update Pretests" %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you in advance for any insight!

Comment: Don't have a better way in mind (either in Rails or SQL), but id put those 2 updates under a transaction so that other threads/processes/servers don't see the intermediate state. At least then from outside it looks exactly like you set them all directly.

Comment: How's your form set up? If you have control over the HTML I recommend taking a look at the documentation for [`check_box` here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)...In the gotcha they describe that they create a hidden input with the value of '0' that gets submitted along with the checkbox and then rails parameter parsing gets rid of the '0' if a '1' is present. Then you just update each one as your normally would, having either a '0' or a '1' sent in the form for each check box. If you don't want to use their helper, the idea stands

Comment: I updated my question to include the view. It iterates through all of the objective_seminars, which is the join table between objectives and seminars. The returned parameters appear to include only the ids of the joins that have been checked. I'm not seeing any zeros in the parameters, probably because the form is sending an array of many records. But I'm willing to refactor the form if there is a way that fits better with convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the responses I've gotten, it doesn't appear that there is a more rails-y way of doing this for my particular setup. But I at least took Fire Lancer's suggestion of ensuring that there is no intermediate state. Now my controller looks like this:

```
def update_pretests
        @seminar = Seminar.find(params[:seminar_id])
        @seminar.objective_seminars.where.not(:id => params[:pretest_on]).update_all(:pretest => 0)
        @seminar.objective_seminars.where(:id => params[:pretest_on]).update_all(:pretest => 1)
        redirect_to priorities_seminar_path(@seminar)
    end
```

I'm still interested if anybody else has insight into this question.